# syntax error in a mysql statement

Tags: mysql

what is the error in the following mysql statement :

```
mysql> SELECT columnName  FROM tableName WHERE columnName LIKE  '%' + @variableName + '%';
```

Comment: Dunno. What did the MySQL REPL tell you it is?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not concat strings using "+" symbol.

```
SELECT columnName 
FROM tableName 
WHERE columnName LIKE CONCAT('%',@variableName,'%');
```

Answer (score 0):

or

SELECT columnName 
FROM tableName 
WHERE columnName LIKE '%@variableName%';